# 2nd order phase transition trouble deriving coefficient in fluctuations analysis

Tags: statistical-mechanics, phase-transition

I can't get one of the coefficients in the equation for $T < T_c$ in the bottom, specifically the equation with the factor of two. any help appreciated.

Consider an ising type  expansion of the free energy density in the order parameter $\psi$. (the mean values of $\psi$ corresponding to a uniform configuration.)

\begin{equation}
 f(T,\psi) = f_0  + G(\nabla\psi)^2+ A\psi^2  + B\psi^4
 \end{equation}
\begin{equation} 
 \bar{\psi} = \begin{cases}  \pm\sqrt{\frac{-A}{2B}}  & \qquad T < T_c \\
                              0 & \qquad  T > T_c
 \end{cases}
 \end{equation}

these solutions come from minimizing the free energy density.
      Expanding the coefficients near the critical temperature, we have
      \begin{equation}
      A = at + ...  
      \end{equation}
      \begin{equation}
           B = B_0 + ... 
      \end{equation}
      \begin{equation}
      G=  G_0 + ...  
      \end{equation}
Where $t=T-T_c$. Then evaluating the free energy density at $\psi = \bar\psi$  we get
  \begin{equation}
  \left. f(T,\psi)\right|_{\psi=\bar{\psi}} = \begin{cases} f_0 - \frac{a^2t^2}{4B_0}  & \qquad T < T_c \\
                                                            f_0  & \qquad T>T_C \end{cases}
  \end{equation}
 To study fluctuations in the order paramater define, $\delta\psi = \psi -\bar{\psi}$.

\begin{equation}
  \delta\psi = \begin{cases} 
                               \psi & \text{in symmetrical phase} \\
                 \psi - \sqrt{\frac{-at}{2B_0}}  & \text{in disordered phase}
             \end{cases}
  \end{equation}

We now calculate the change in free energy though I am not sure how exactly to calculate this, for some
reason I am missing something simple I'm sure (!).

\begin{equation}
  \Delta F(T,\delta\psi) = \begin{cases}  
            \int d^{d}r\,\left( G(\nabla\delta \psi)^2 + at\delta \psi^2\right) & \qquad T > T_c \\
            \int d^{d}r\,\left( G(\nabla\delta \psi)^2 -2at\delta \psi^2\right)   & \qquad T < T_c
             \end{cases}
  \end{equation}

I have spent some time trying to calculate the coefficient above for $\delta\psi^2$ for $T < T_c$. I am clearly not understanding something here, 
  since when I calculate $f(\psi) - f(\bar{\psi})$ I do not get the above expression. In fact I am not sure exactly how to go about calculating this.  Landau and Lifshitz gives the above 
  coefficient in section 146 "Fluctuations of the Order Parameter".  I am also confused because it seems like there are two values of the mean $\bar{\psi} = \pm (\frac{-at}{2B_0})^\frac{1}{2} $ however in the book I only see a reference to the positive square root. This topic is a bit obscure so I'm not sure anybody really is gonna be able to help, but I'd appreciate any insight.

Answer (score 1):

To get the coefficient, you just have to expand the free energy up to $\delta\psi^2$. The linear term gives zero (because you're expanding around the minimum) whereas the quadratic term is $A+6B\bar\psi^2$, which gives the expected result. You can see that this result is independent of the minimum choose (independent of the sign).